# PHPMailer is sending emails successfully, but they are not appearing in the sandbox account. What could be causing this and how to fix it?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpmailer, amazon-ses

I'm using PHPMailer to send emails from my web application, and while the emails are being sent successfully, they are not appearing in my sandbox email account for testing and verification. What could be causing this issue, and how can I ensure that the emails are being delivered to the sandbox account as expected? Are there any specific settings or configurations that need to be adjusted in PHPMailer or the email client to ensure successful delivery to the sandbox account?

I am using PHPMailer Laravel from Amazon SES. My account is not in a sandbox. My problem is when I try to email the admin panel Laravel on my site to my clients. I am informed that it was sent successfully. But when I check my clients' inbox, spam and trash the email was not received. When I test my site using the public form I can successfully send the email and receive it in my inbox. Before I could not even send and receive the email by the public form of my site, because it gave error:   Get set up but error is appearing: stream_socket_enable_crypto (): Peer certificate = `email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'```` I was able to resolve this error by entering Cpanel, WHM, SMTP Restrictions, the option was enabled, I disabled it. Fixed the public form issue but now I have problem with admin panel. I use the Vultr server to host the site and amazon WorkMail to receive the emails.

mail.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "ses",
    |            "sparkpost", "log", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Markdown Mail Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
    | theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
    | of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
    |
    */
   
    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

.env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=live
APP_KEY=base64:2t/r95eojKWVGAlH44ZV5mu5qa5Q+aexXY/F1A/Y=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_INSTALL=false
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost/softwarezon_signal_mod5

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=sinaisde_**
DB_USERNAME=sinaisde_**
DB_PASSWORD=**********

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=AK9A1APWPA1C6R******
MAIL_PASSWORD=BTsZ3PRE+************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

PURCHASE_CODE=SOFTWAREZON_DEFAULT_CODE
BUYER_USERNAME=softwarezon
```

services.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Third Party Services
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This file is for storing the credentials for third party services such
    | as Stripe, Mailgun, SparkPost and others. This file provides a sane
    | default location for this type of information, allowing packages
    | to have a conventional place to find your various credentials.
    |
    */

    'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
        'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
    ],

    'ses' => [
        'key' => env('SES_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('SES_SECRET'),
        'region' => 'us-east-1',
    ],

    'sparkpost' => [
        'secret' => env('SPARKPOST_SECRET'),
    ],

    'stripe' => [
        'model' => App\User::class,
        'key' => env('STRIPE_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('STRIPE_SECRET'),
    ],

];
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using the `smtp` driver and not the `ses` driver?

Comment: @matticustard is right, your driver is ses, and obviously you have to install the AWS package. I use SES too, I've set encryption to null.

Comment: If you're using standard Laravel, you're not using PHPMailer.